# How to merge two APK into single so that both apps can be installed at the same time

Tags: android

How to merge 2 Android apps into bundle so that when I install the bundle both the app are installed? I want to merge 2 APKs into a single bundle so that I can upload it on Android Market and when somebody installs it on the device then both the apps should installed on the device.

Answer (score 3):

If these two apps have no overlaps, you only need to merge the AndroidManifest.xml, res and src folders.

Keep two activities with the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

will make you have two launch entrance in Launcher.

In fact, it's one app with one apk. But since have two launchable activities, user will feel like they have installed two apps with one apk.

Comment: Thanks Johnny. Basically I have 2 apk files and do not have the manifest file or code base for another. So finally I want to merge 2 apk files. any possibility?

Comment: aapt might work for you. (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aapt.html) the thing I'm not sure here is that whether the two binary manifest file could be merged

Comment: I will have a try of it and let u know.

Comment: I sincerely hope that cannot be done, otherwise it's a security hole. Malicious app can then inject themselves into legacy apps.

Comment: The second reason I think that's not possible is because apk are being signed, two apks will have different signature, which will change if somehow the structure of the apk changes somehow.