# Bundling multiple apps I have created into one .apk file

Tags: android, installation, apk

Is it possible to bundle an app and the app settings into one apk file? so I can change the app settings from the "App settings"

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If these two apps have no overlaps, you only need to merge the AndroidManifest.xml, res and src folders.

Keep two activities with the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

will make you have two launch entrances in Launcher.

In fact, it's one app with one apk. But since have two launchable activities, user will feel like they have installed two apps with one apk.

Found answer on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074695/how-to-merge-2-android-apps-2-apk-into-single-so-that-when-i-install-the-bundle)

Comment: I have actually seen that question, and unfortunetly they do have overlap :(