# Download one app and install 2 apps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

Is there any possibility to create an application for iphone/ipad and when user download that single application but it will install 2 applications.

i.e. one download but installed 2 app.

What I want to do is to merge 2 iphone application into 1 and when that is installed than it would be installing as 2 different apps.

For android [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074695/how-to-merge-2-android-apps-2-apk-into-single-so-that-when-i-install-the-bundle) is there and from answer I guess it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As posted above, there aren't APIs. Apple will never, ever approve such an application as its basically downloading executable code...

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. Imagine how confusing this would be to the user.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Their are no APIs that would allow you start installation of another app on an Apple device, unless it's a rooted phone.

Answer (score 2):

Why? - Why not just merge the two apps together? - There is no way Apple would allow this... ever.

Answer (score 1):

```
For android similar question is there and from answer I guess it is possible.
```

Please remember that iPhone and Android are two different programming paradigms. So if Android provides something, it does not mean Apple has to follow the suit or vice versa. The only way you could do it is on a rooted device with third party app installers.