# Can i "combine" multiple .apk in the same .apk file?

Tags: android, bundle, apk, google-play

My application consists of two different .apk files, one client and one server. Is there a way to produce one .apk file for it, to upload on Android Market?

Will the users be able to uninstall the one they don't need? When the users install the bundle are they prompted to pick which one they want to install?

Comment: Same question here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074695/how-to-merge-two-apk-into-single-so-that-both-apps-can-be-installed-at-the-same

Comment: So basically it will be one application with two different activities one for client one for server and the user will pick which one to run from the launcher? ty