# One .apk file that installs two apps

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, apk

This is a question concerning android applications with two different .apks (or two apps contained in the one .apk file)

I have two apps which do completely different things but are related, say one is a standard user app and one is an admin app. But a user can be both a user and an admin. I am wondering is it possible for me to create one .apk file that installs two applications to the phone? And how would I got about this?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on your definition of "application". You cannot install 2 applications if you use the more official definition, as you can have only 1 `<application>` in your `manifest.xml`

You can define several activities in your `manifest.xml`, and they can do seperate things, so in that way YOU CAN have 2 things a person might describe as "application" in one `APK`

Just define multiple activities and use those could be defined as an option, but it depends on your definition of 'application', but in this case I'd say it would work

Comment: Just solution sounds like it would suit...do you have a link to it on the Android developers wiki, I can't see it, thanks

Comment: Sure: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html . You are declaring every activity anyway, so it's no big deal really. You should have an intent-filter for it being a launcher, just like your first activity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER

Answer (score 14):

You can have two activity elements in the same manifest file, which have both the intent filter with *action=MAIN* and *category=LAUNCHER*. Further, you have also to use the attribute "*android:taskAffinity*" for both activity elements (see also [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-beginners/ATJI7beqYzs/oB6q2HmjvmsJ)):

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"        
             android:icon="@drawable/main_icon"
             android:label="@string/main_name"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
             
    <activity android:name="com.foobar.MyActivity2"            
              android:taskAffinity="com.foobar.MyActivity2"
              android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
              android:label="@string/name1" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action   android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"       />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        
    
    <activity android:name="com.foobar.MyActivity2"
              android:taskAffinity="com.foobar.MyActivity2"
              android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
              android:label="@string/name2" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action   android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"       />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>             
    
</application>
```

When the APK file with this manifest is installed on a device, then it will create two icons on the homescreen. The titles of these icons will be taken from the attributes *android:label*, and the icons will be taken from the attributes *android:icon*. In the list of apps under *"Settings | Apps"* you will see the name & icon defined by the attributes of the application tag. When you choose "uninstall" for this entry in the list of apps, then both "apps" will be removed from the device.

Comment: how do i merge the two apks to make them into a single app

Comment: "Merging two APKs" means that you do not have the source code of the apps, doesn't it? This question is discussed there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074695. The problem is that for this you had to merge the two classes.dex, and also the AndroidManifest.xml, which is contained in binary form in the APK file.

Comment: i am trying to create an app like LOCKET
so i have an apk for LockScreen since i have made it LAUNCHER in the manifest and i have an apk for MainScreen inside the app which is also Launcher in my manifest. I have only one manifest file thats why i get 2 apks on the launcher.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install multiple apps by just installing one app.

In Manifest.xml
[image]

Project Structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should either build **2 APKs** are use [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html).

Btw, this is a security measure.

Comment: using the .apk expansion files will not install the second apk (i think)

Comment: Yes @Thepoosh Expansion files are only added if the apk file size >50MB

Answer (score 0):

No.

what you can do is to check if the second app is already installed, and if the answer is no, you can prompt the request to install the second app using [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html) post.