# How to merge two .apk files and make one .apk file?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, apk

I have two .apk files i want to merge them and make one .apk file. can it possible to merge two .apk files and make one .apk file and get thair functionality???

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Maybe this one also helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149805/bundle-two-apk-into-a-single-apk

Comment: Go through this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149805/bundle-two-apk-into-a-single-apk

Answer (score 0):

Perfect solution: [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682576/one-apk-file-that-installs-two-apps:)

It depends on your definition of `application`. You cannot install 2 applications if you use the more official definition, as you can have only 1  in your manifest.xml

You can define several activities in your `manifest.xml`, and they can do seperate things, so in that way YOU CAN have 2 things a person might describe as `application` in one `APK`

Just define multiple activities and use those could be defined as an option, but it depends on your definition of `application`, but in this case I'd say it would work.