# Android Single App, Multiple APK

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Recently installed Google Dialer App from Play store. One interesting thing noticed is after Dialer App install it doesnt created as separate App, instead new tab in Google Hangout was created. As developer, How it is possible do that? Is there way to divide a single one to multiple APK and publish in Play store as different App?

Comment: yeah its possible you need to add multiple launchers/intent-filter at manifest for multiple activities

Comment: @AnkushBist thanks for immediate response, kindly provide bit more details or any link if available .

Comment: have you just started in android or have enough knowledge to develop an android application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.Google provides support for **Multiple APK**.

There can be multiple use cases where we can just divide our APK to one or two.

**Use Cases**:

Different APK for,

- Mobile and Tablet (Supporting multiple screens)
- Hardware features
- API Levels
- GL Textures
- CPU Architecture

For more information please check out: https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"        
         android:icon="@drawable/main_icon"
         android:label="@string/main_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity android:name="com.foobar.MyActivity2"            
          android:taskAffinity="com.foobar.MyActivity2"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
          android:label="@string/name1" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action   android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"       />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>        

<activity android:name="com.foobar.MyActivity2"
          android:taskAffinity="com.foobar.MyActivity2"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon1"
          android:label="@string/name2" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action   android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"       />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This is here you can create multiple launchers from on application.
Each launchers will redirect to the specified activity/screen decided by you at the time of apk compilation.

can find more about this at [Multiple launchers from single apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682576/one-apk-file-that-installs-two-apps)